# No runtime provider for RuntimeCompiler

Tags: angular, angular2-providers

I'm trying to follow the accepted answer here, and make a call to RuntimeCompiler.clearCache()

Here's how I've tried to do it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RuntimeCompiler } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache();
    }   
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for RuntimeCompiler!
```

What am I missing to here?

Answer (score 2):

With RC5+ this providers should be registered on a AppModule level

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule
        ...
    ],
    declarations: [ ... ],
    bootstrap:    [ ... ],
    providers: [
        COMPILER_PROVIDERS
    ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Check this [How can I use/create dynamic template to compile dynamic Component with Angular 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38888008/1679310) for a working plunker

Answer (score 2):

Remove the line

```
import { RuntimeCompiler } from '@angular/compiler';
```

Then add Compiler to import @angular/core. And replace RuntimeCompiler to Compiler;

```
import { Component, Compiler } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _compiler: Compiler) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this._compiler.clearCache();
    }   
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Add `RuntimeCompiler` to your component providers. (`providers: [RuntimeCompiler]`, below `templateUrl`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I add the `providers` I now get: `No provider for CompileMetadataResolver! `.

Answer (score 1):

Add RuntimeCompiler as provider in your `component`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RuntimeCompiler } from '@angular/compiler';

@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,
   selector: 'my-app',
   templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
   providers: [RuntimeCompiler]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _runtimeCompiler: RuntimeCompiler) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this._runtimeCompiler.clearCache();
  }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I add the `providers` I now get: `No provider for CompileMetadataResolver! `.

Comment: @Juicy, which version of ng do you use? according to official api, is there is like simple `Compiler` class without `Runtime`, check (this link)[https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was looking in to it. It does have the `clearCache` method but I'm not sure how to use this... `import {Compiler} from '@angular/compiler` tells me that there is no exported member called `Compiler`. I'm using latest `@angular` from `npm` which I think is `RC5`.

Comment: @Juicy, try to import {Compiler} from '@angular/core